Explicit sampling with a random conditional covariance matrix
Let $\mathbf X = (x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ be a zero-mean random vector which has conditional covariance
$$
\Sigma_\xi
\equiv
\operatorname{cov}[x_i,x_j| \xi]=\frac{1}{N}\left(
\sigma^2 \delta_{ij}
+
\sum_{\mu=1}^K
\xi_i^\mu
\xi_j^\mu
\right)
$$
where $\xi = \left[\xi^\mu_i\right]$ is a random matrix whose elements are are IID normal random variables:
$$
\operatorname{E}[\xi_i^\mu] = 0,\qquad
\operatorname{E}[\xi_i^\mu\xi_j^\nu] = \frac{\sigma_\xi^2}{K} \delta_{ij}\delta_{\mu\nu}
$$
If it were possible to find some matrix $A_\xi$ such that $A_\xi = \sqrt{\Sigma_\xi}$ or which is the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma_\xi$, then it would be possible to write $\mathbf X$ solely in terms of independent random variables:
$$
\mathbf X = A_\xi \mathbf Z,
$$
where $\mathbf Z$ is a vector of IID standard normal variables. In particular, $\mathbf Z$ is independent of $A_\xi$.
Is there any analytic expression for $A_\xi$? I imagine there might be some way to approach this problem in the limit of large $N$ and $K$ with $N/K = \Theta(1)$ because the term involving $\xi$ in the conditional covariance may be thought of as a low-rank perturbation to the identity matrix. I could also imagine that a power series approximation could be applied for the square root.
A similar question is: is there a way to parameterize both $\mathbf X$ and $\xi$ in terms of some common set of IID random variables in a manner that is analytically tractable for other purposes?
